How to find the velocity of a particle whose position is given in cylindical coordinates, and has a position dependent force?
I have a question where a particle mass m has position given in cylindrical coordinates, so its position looks like this:
$$\underline{r}=r\cos\theta\underline{e_1}+r\sin\theta\underline{e_2}+z\underline{e_3}$$,
which I don't really understand the formulation of. Then the force is position dependent, which is where the problems really begin, I don't know whether r and theta are time-dependent as the question doesn't say, but we want to find the kinetic energy of this particle, so I'm assuming I want the velocity.
$$\underline{F}=-\lambda r^2(\cos\theta\underline{e_1}+\sin\theta\underline{e_2})+\lambda z^2\underline{e_3}$$
Lambda is a constant
Ive thought about integrating with respect to time but something doesn't feel right and i don't know what, like i don't know how to get the initial velocity if i integrate between o and t, or how to find the constant of integration if i do an indefinite integral.
Any help or pointers to a good resource would be greatly appreciated.
For context this is a second year degree level classical mechanics module

Using r as the position vector as well seems confusion. Are there any initial conditions?

One way would be to write everything in Cartesian coordinates and try to solve the equations of motion. That's not trivial in this case. But there is a simple change of variables that would make the problem simpler. For a point described by $\vec r$ use a coordinate system with $\hat r_{||}$ along the projection in the horizontal plane, $\hat r_\perp$ also in the horizontal plane, perpendicular to $\hat r_{||}$, and $\hat z$. Then you have $$\vec r=r\hat r_{||}+z\hat z$$ and $$\vec F=-\lambda r^2\hat r_{||}+\lambda z^2\hat z$$
Let's assume that the initial conditions are $\vec r(0)=r_o\hat r_{||}+z_0\hat z$ and $\vec v(0)=v_{0,||}\hat r_{||}+v_{0,\perp}\hat r_{\perp}+v_{0,z}\hat z$.
The first thing to notice is that there is no force along $\hat r_\perp$. Therefore $$r_\perp(t)=v_{0,\perp}t$$
Writing the equations for the other directions is easy:
$$\hat r_{||}:  m\ddot r=-\lambda r^2\\\hat z:m\ddot z=\lambda z^2$$
Solving these is not trivial (it involves the Weierstrass elliptic function).
